# How to submit a sitemap for a dynamic website?

Tags: xml-sitemap

I created a dynamic sitemap, where I generate links from database and output an XML as the result (https://ufotoday.com/sitemap)

Now, since this sitemap is changing all the time, do I need to anything to make google re-scan the sitemap (I'm not sure if they do it by default)

**UPDATE:**

I'm still unable to confirm with any google official resources that in fact the sitemap is being resubmitted automatically (and discovers new items that show up in the dynamic sitemap), it will be great if anyone can confirm that this is what happening based on their own experience.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google have a few pages on managing your sitemaps at https://support.google.com/webmasters/topic/4581190?hl=en&ref_topic=4581352

Google recommend you either submit your sitemap using the [Search Console sitemap tool](https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/sitemap-list)
or add a line to your robots.txt, so in your example:

`Sitemap: https://ufotoday.com/sitemap`

You shouldn't need to regularly resubmit your sitemap as Google will pick up changes. If your content changes frequently then search engines will crawl more frequently.

Comment: Do you know for fact that Google will resubmit the sitemap? (how do you know) also, how often does it happen? Thanks!

Comment: @Yovav from 'Learn about sitemaps`: "Search engine web crawlers like Googlebot read this file to more intelligently crawl your site".

Google have [an FAQ page](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/34439?hl=en) which confirms its crawler frequency depends on a number of factors for individual sites. There's also a link there to guidelines on improving your content for a better chance of Google indexing and ranking higher in searches.

Comment: I tend to agree, but I still cannot find it in writing in any of the links that in fact the sitemap is being resubmitted automatically. they are all talking about the crawler re-scanning URLs that were already submitted in the sitemap, but what about new items that show up in the sitemap... I'm still unable to confirm this with any official google resource.

Comment: @Yovav I've never seen it explicitly stated - I find Google's documentation around search tends to be quite vague. In my experience working with a site that's regularly updated (at least once per week), our content appears in Google search results very quickly, certainly within a day - that's using sitemaps, not submitting directly to Google.